# Finite-dimensional subspace normed vector space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I know that probably this question has already been answered, but I'd like to present my attempt of solution.

Let $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space and let $F\subseteq E$ be a finite-dimensional subspace. Suppose that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} F=n$.

First of all I proved the following lemma.

**Lemma 1** Every finite-dimensional normed vector space is complete.

Then, I noticed that $(F,\|\cdot\|_{F})$ is a finite-dimensional normed vector space, where $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ is the induced norm. So, $F$ is complete by *Lemma 1*.

**Lemma 2** If  $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space such that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}{E}=n$, then $E$ is algebraically and topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

By *Lemma 2*, I can view $F$ as a complete subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is itself complete, I can conclude that $F$ is closed. Here I used the fact that every complete subspace of a complete space is closed.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: doesn't completeness from Lemma 1 imply closedness?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The part with lemma 2 isn't necessary. Any complete subspace of a metric space is closed. So the proposition follows directly from lemma 1 and you don't need to assume that $E$ is finite-dimensional. But can you prove lemma 1?

Actually even if you use just “complete subspace of complete space is closed” you don't need lemma 2 since both $E$, $F$ are complete by lemma 1.

On the other hand lemma 1 is a consequence of lemma 2. That's because a homeomorphism between normed linear spaces which is also linear isomorphism preserves completeness. It is so because the mapping is then bilipschitz which goes from the following fact:

For a linear map between normed linear spaces the following are equivalent:

1. it is bounded
2. it is lipschitz
3. it is continuous
4. it is continuous at zero

The only non-trivial implication is $(4) \implies (1)$. By continuity at zero, there is $δ > 0$ such that $f[B(0, δ)] ⊆ B(f(0), 1)$. But then $f[B(0, 1)] ⊆ B(f(0), \frac{1}{δ})$ and $\lVert f(x)\rVert ≤ \frac{1}{δ}\lVert x \rVert$ for every $x$ by linearity.

Comment: Why is its consequence? Does any linear and topological isomorphism preserve completeness?

Comment: @avati91 Yes, you are right. It preserves just complete metrizability. But maybe it can be strengthened. However there is no point in proving completeness of $F$ by lemma 1 while proving completeness of $E$ by lemma 2, which is incorrect as you said.

Comment: @avati91 Actually a homeomorphism between two normed spaces which is linear isomorphism preserves completeness, because it is both lipschitz and inverse lipschitz.

Comment: @avati91 Yes, it holds.

Comment: If $T:(E,\|\cdot\|_E)\to (F,\|\cdot\|_F)$ is a linear and topological isomorphism, then it is also a bi-Lipschitz map. But...why? Which is the Lipschitz constant?

Comment: @avati91 If the inverse is continuous, then its bounded (i.e. Lipschitz)...right?  In fact, you just need a *continuous* linear isomorphism by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: I don't agree with you. This theorem, a corollary of the Open Mapping Theorem, applies only if you have to do with Banach Spaces...

Comment: @avati91 you don't need the open mapping theorem if you're already assuming a homeomorphism.  I was just trying to give a stronger statement. user8790's answer looks right.

Comment: Let $T:(E,\|\cdot\|_E)\to (F,\|\cdot\|_F)$ be an algebraic and topological isomorphism. I have to find $L>0$ such that for every $x\in E$  $1/L\|x\|_E\le \|Tx\|_F\le  L\|x\|_E$

Comment: @avati91  that's correct. Do you see why, if T is a linear homeomorphism, then $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are bounded operators?

Comment: Is it true that $\frac{1}{\|T^{-1}\|}=\|T\|$?

Comment: @studiosus I don't think so, but once you admit $||T^{-1}||<\infty$, then choose some $L > max \{ ||T||, ||T^{-1}|| \}$.  Then $||T^{-1}(Tx)|| \leq L ||T(x)|| \leq L^{2} ||x||$. Now divide by $L$.