# Prove that there is no countable base to a complete normed space

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

**Defenition**(to make sure we are talking about the same thing) :

> A base $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots \}$ to a normic space $X$ is a group of elements from $X$, that satisfies the following condition : $\forall x\in X$, $x$ can be written as a *finite* linear combination of elements from $B$.

I need to prove that a complete normic space has no countable base.
What I tried :
Let's assume we have a countable base : $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots \}$
We would like to show that we can write $X$ as a countable union of nowhere dense set's, and then we will get a contridiction for Baire categoty theorome.
I didn't find a way how to make these nowhere dense groups, I thought to let $A_i$ be the group of elements from $X$ which can be written as a linear combintaion of elements from $B$ with exactly $i$ elements, the union is indeed all the space, but I failed to show that it is nowhere dense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're almost right about the sets, even more easily:

Define $B_n$ to be the linear span of $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ for every $n$.

Then every $B_n$ is closed and has empty interior.

Closedness is clear, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/854227/4280) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1383132/4280).

Nowhere denseness (i.e. empty interior in this case) follows from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148859/4280).

Searching does help, you see...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** consider these subspaces $F_n = Span(b_1,...,b_n)$

What can you say about them ?