# Is $U=$ {$ax, a \in R$} closed subset of normed infinite dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let X be infinite dimensional normed vector space over $R$. Let $U=$ {$ax, a \in R$} $V=$ {$bx, b \in R$}. Is $U$ closed set? Is $U+V$ closed set?

Sequence from $U$ is $a_nx$ and if it is convergent then it intuitively has to be convergent to $ax$ where $a$ is a limit of $a_n$ so the limit is still in $U$ however I can't prove formally that $a_n$ converges to $y \in X$ implies $y=kx$ for some $k \in R$.

Is $U+V$ closed? $U+V=$ {$ax+by : a,b \in R$}. (Also very important for me question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finite-dimensional subspace normed vector space is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854227/finite-dimensional-subspace-normed-vector-space-is-closed) or this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764798

Comment: No my question is about Infinite dimensional space

Comment: So are these posts. Your question is about subspaces of dimension 0,1, or 2 in that infinite dimensional space. This is a particular case of these posts.